# understanding the description of logits and labels in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, softmax

This is what tensorflow has to say about the logits and labels arguments in `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`

> Args:
>     _sentinel: Used to prevent positional parameters. Internal, do not use.
>
> labels: `Tensor` of shape `[d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}]` (where `r` is rank of
>       `labels` and result) and dtype `int32` or `int64`. Each entry in `labels`
>       must be an index in `[0, num_classes)`. Other values will raise an
>       exception when this op is run on CPU, and return `NaN` for corresponding
>       loss and gradient rows on GPU.
>
> logits: Unscaled log probabilities of shape
>       `[d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}, num_classes]` and dtype `float32` or `float64`.
>     name: A name for the operation (optional).

I have worked on my fair share of machine learning and deep learning classification problems and the only output shape that i have come across or even think of is [None, 1] or [None, number of classes](if the sparse implementation is not implemented.)

Please shed some light on where do:  `Tensor` (labels) of shape `[d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}]` and 'Tensor' (logits) Unscaled log probabilities of shape
    `[d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}, num_classes]` come from. Maybe just an example would  suffice

Answer (score 0):

> I have worked on my fair share of machine learning and deep learning classification problems and the only output shape that i have come across or even think of is [None, 1] or [None, number of classes]

This is exactly what you are describing.

> labels: Tensor of shape [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}] (where r is rank of  labels and result) and dtype int32 or int64. Each entry in labels must be an index in [0, num_classes).

d_0, d_1 ... d_{r-1} are examples of your batch. Here this correspond to a tensor of shape [r, 1] where r is your batch_size.

> logits: Unscaled log probabilities of shape  [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}, num_classes]

Same thing here, this correspond to a tensor of shape [r, num_classes].

When we define the model, r = None as we don't want the graph to be batch size dependant.